# C - delete number from array,wont delete more instances of same number only one

Tags: c, arrays

my code only deletes one number of for example 3 instances of that same number,

```
int n,i,va,x;
int arr[100];
int *ptr;
srand(time(NULL));
printf("array size");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i = 0 ; i<n; i++)
{
    va = (rand()%10);
    arr[i] = va;
}
for(i = 0 ; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
}

printf("number you wanna delete :");
scanf("%d",&x);

ptr = arr;  //pointer
```

bellow is the code im looking to fix

```
for(i = 0; i<n; i++,*ptr++)   
{
    if(*ptr == x)
    {
        for(i = i; i<n; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
        }
    }
}
n--;
```

printing new array

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("new array - %d\n",arr[i]);
}
```

heres my result - it only delets first instance of that number but not the rest

[image]

Comment: Have you used a debugger to trace the execution of your program? `for(i = i; i<n; i++)` that looks wrong. The `i` variable is shared between inner and outer `for` loops. So when the inner loop finishes the variable value is no longer correct for the outer loops use.

Comment: Would you include your `#include` statements please? It's hard to this to debug without a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: only #include <stdio.h>

Comment: Your code has two warnings that point at the problem. Turn on warnings with `-Wall`. The code won't make sense with just stdio.h, it needs stdlib.h for rand and srand and time.h for time.

Comment: im working this code in codeblocks no errors,i also posted picture of program

Comment: @joki00 It might work on your particular IDE, but it's not valid C and won't work in a standards compliant C compiler. This is why I don't like IDEs. Here's the docs for [time()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_time.htm) and for [srand()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_srand.htm).

Comment: when calling `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: if the user enters 101 (or greater) or enters any alphabetic value the code will fail.  This needs to be fixed.  Note: C now has VLA` variable length arrays.  So get the value from the user first, then declare the array using that value from the user for the size of the array

Comment: thanks @kaylum you were right i = i was mistake i made new variable j for that and it works now!

Comment: the code has the logic error: each time a number is removed from the array, the length of the array `n` needs to be decremented by 1  Otherwise the last x numbers will be printed, even though they are not actually still part of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling this with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) (after putting it in `main` and including only stdio.h as [the OP said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472536/c-delete-number-from-array-wont-delete-more-instances-of-same-number-only-one#comment62443727_37472536)) I get a fistful of warnings.

```
$ make
cc -Wall -g    test.c   -o test
test.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'srand' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    srand(time(NULL));
    ^
test.c:7:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'time' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    srand(time(NULL));
          ^
test.c:12:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'rand' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        va = (rand()%10);
              ^
test.c:26:19: warning: explicitly assigning value of variable of type 'int' to itself
      [-Wself-assign]
            for(i = i; i<n; i++) {
                ~ ^ ~
test.c:24:25: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++,*ptr++) {
                        ^~~~~~
5 warnings generated.
```

The first three are fixed by including stdlib.h and time.h. Something to learn about C: just because it happens to work doesn't mean it's going to work for anyone else or even the next time it's run. A different compiler, a different operating system, or a stiff breeze can make a lot of "working" but incorrect C code fail. Find all the warnings and strictures provided by your IDE and turn them all on.

The last two point at the problem. Let's see them again.

```
$ make
cc -Wall -g    test.c   -o test
test.c:28:19: warning: explicitly assigning value of variable of type 'int' to itself
      [-Wself-assign]
            for(i = i; i<n; i++) {
                ~ ^ ~
test.c:26:25: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++,*ptr++) {
                        ^~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
```

`i` is being incremented in an inner loop which is also using `i`. As soon as it finds the thing in question, the outer loop will stop. That can be fixed by using a new counter for the inner loop, `j`.

```
for(i = 0; i<n; i++,*ptr++) {
    if(*ptr == x) {
        for(int j = i; j<n; j++) {
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        }
    }
}
n--;
```

Now it works... sort of. The next problem is the `n--` after the loop which assumes only one element was removed. But any number of elements were removed, so it has to be decremented each time. `n--` goes inside the loop.

```
for(i = 0; i<n; i++,*ptr++) {
    if(*ptr == x) {
        for(int j = i; j<n; j++) {
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        }
        n--;
    }
}
```

Finally, there's the warning about `*ptr--`. I see what's going on, and it's clever... but too clever. It's hard to follow what's going on. There's no need for `*ptr`, just access the array elements with `arr[i]`.

```
for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == x) {
        for(int j = i; j<n; j++) {
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        }
        n--;
    }
}
```

Removing a bunch of unnecessary variables, providing more descriptive variable names, and initializing counters as needed, we get...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int numbers[100];
    int size = 0;
    int to_delete;

    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("array size: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++) {
        numbers[i] = (rand()%10);
        printf("%d\n",numbers[i]);
    }

    printf("number you wanna delete: ");
    scanf("%d",&to_delete);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(numbers[i] == to_delete) {
            for(int j = i; j < size; j++) {
                numbers[j] = numbers[j+1];
            }
            size--;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("new array - %d\n",numbers[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now see if you can do it without the inner loop.

Comment: Btw, I'm not sure if OP uses C99. He declares all his variables at the beginning of the function, which suggests C89, so I'm assuming he has to work in that. I think you should change your answer around a bit to conform C89. Just a thought though.

Comment: i need pointers because it asks so in assignment,but i saw my mistake at   i = i,should've been i = j i realized that later,thanks,much appreciated

Comment: @adam10603 Based on their comments I don't think the OP knows about C standards at all (no offense meant, OP). When I see a style like that I assume they're learning from an outdated source. Every major compiler supports C99 or at least the relaxed declaration of variables, even Visual C++ (finally). The improvements are so worth it that I'll very conservatively default to C99, especially if you're learning C in 2016!

Comment: @joki00 I think that you inconsistently use `arr[j]` in the inner loop "points" out the problem with the inner loop (get it?). You should be able to do it just by incrementing `*ptr` with no inner loop and a single pass through the array.

Comment: @Schwern none taken i'm just beginner,still learning,long way to go

Comment: @Schwern That is very true, but at my university for example, they explicitly teach C89, and we have to use VS2010, which is only compatible with C89 (well kind of... VS always uses a mixed set of features from different standards of C/C++). OP might be in a similar situation.

Comment: @adam10603 Yuck. I'm sympathetic, but I'm not going to eschew some of the most important fixes to C because universities make bad decisions, and it's good for students to see how C is written outside of uni or the Microsoft stack. I'm curious if my code generates any warnings. AFAIK the only non-ANSI thing I did was declare `i` in a for loop. Surely even VS2010 must allow that.

Comment: @Schwern It does not. And the worst part it that it doesn't even generate a meaningful error message when you declare a variable in a for loop for example. You just get all kinds of nonsense errors. But after a while you get used to it... If I see a whole bunch of nonsense errors, I already know I must have declared something further in the body. I don't like C to begin with, I much prefer modern C++, but sticking to C89 especially drives me nuts. I have no idea why we are required to program in C89 in 2016 :(